# Randomly getting HTTP 400 errors while scraping

Tags: http, screen-scraping

My scraping program usually works, but it occassionally gets a HTTP 400 error from the server.  There is no lasting throttle effect; it goes back to working immediately after the 400 response..  I'd estimate that ~1/5000 of the responses I get are 400's, while the rest are success (200's).  What could be going on.. anything I could do to eliminate these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http 400 is bad request.

There is something in the request that the server is reacting to. It will not affect any other requests.

A typical cause of this is special characters is a string.

Best way to fix it is to find the root cause, try logging all request if this is possible in your environment.